# Focus textbox in panel using autoscroll in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm getting a problem when i try to scroll down to textbox 4 and 5 and try to click the mouse cursor to the textbox 4 the screen goes up to textbox 1,2 and 3

the panel is set to autoscroll = true;
[image]

What I need to do is that whenever i focus the cursor to the textboxes below like 4 and 5, the screen won't go up on a panel.

Comment: Share code please.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I just set the Autoscrollmargin from 0,1000 to 0,0